# Decomposition of $S^7=\operatorname{Spin}(7)/G_2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, reductive-groups, exceptional-groups, octonions

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$The seven-sphere can be written as the reductive space $S^7=\Spin(7)/G_2$. Has the decomposition $\Spin(7)=G_2\times S^7$ been calculated somewhere; maybe in terms of Cayley numbers?

Comment: What makes you think that $Spin(7)=G_2\times S^7$? Think of the Hopf fibration $S^2=S^3/S^1$: would you then conclude that $S^3=S^2\times S^1$?

Comment: @Andre: A result in Helgason says that such a decomposition exists for reductive spaces; at least locally. In the case of $S^2$ we have $SO(3)=SO(2)\times S^2$.

Comment: But that's wrong, Oliver.  $SO(3)$ is not the product of $SO(2)$ and $S^2$. The homotopy groups don't work out.  It's a non-trivial fibre bundle, $SO(2) \to SO(3) \to S^2$

Comment: @Ryan: You're saying that that isn't true locally in some neighborhood?

Comment: The statement $SO(3) = SO(2) \times S^2$ isn't a local statement.  What kind of "local" are you talking about?  If you mean in the sense of fibre bundles, yes there is a fibre bundle, but it is not trivial (as your notation presumes).

Comment: @Ryan: I'm being sloppy; all these equalities are potentially just holding in a neighborhood of some chosen point of the manifold. They can be global however. I just don't know for $S^7$.

Comment: You're also implicitly assuming that there is a preferred way of trivializing the bundle $Spin(7)\to G_2\to S^7$ in a neighborhood of a given point $p\in S^7$. My guess is that there are many ways of locally trivializing that bundle, and that they are all pretty ugly to write down.

Comment: @Andre: I'm making no such assumption. I'm not even approaching the problem from the bundle point of view. As I already mentioned, the result I'm using is in Helgason and it uses the exponential map, not bundles. Results of this type are generally not easy; see my earlier post on Stiefel manifolds: <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139542/>. However, in the case of $S^7$, I wonder if the octonionic structure doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

This is too long for a comment. (But I have now added an answer to the original question.)

As André and Ryan have hinted at in the comments, what you have is a principal fibre bundle $G_2 \to \operatorname{Spin}(7) \stackrel{\pi}{\to} S^7$.  Fibre bundles are locally trivial, so of course around every point of the 7-sphere there is a neighbourhood $U$ so that $\pi^{-1}U \cong U \times G_2$.  The diffeomorphism depends on a choice of section: a way to assign to every point in $U$ a unique element of $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$.

What I know how to describe in terms of octonions (i.e., Cayley numbers) is the above fibre bundle, and maybe this helps you.

Let $\mathbb{O}$ denote the Cayley numbers.  They form an 8-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1,\dots,e_8$, where $e_1,\dots,e_7$ are imaginary units and $e_8 = 1$.  Let $L_i$ denote left multiplication by the imaginary unit $e_i$, for $i=1,\dots, 7$.  The $L_i$ are endomorphisms of $\mathbb{O}$ which obey the Clifford relations
$$ L_i \circ L_j + L_j \circ L_i = \begin{cases} - 2\operatorname{id} & i=j \cr 0 & i\neq j \end{cases}$$
whence they define a linear representation of the Clifford algebra $C\ell(7)$ on $\mathbb{O}$. (You could also use right multiplication and this would give the other inequivalent Clifford module of $C\ell(7)$.  Both Clifford modules turn out to be equivalent under the spin group.)

The spin group $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ naturally lives inside $C\ell(7)$, whence we also have a linear representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ on $\mathbb{O}$.  This is nothing but the spinor representation $\operatorname{Spin}(7) \to \operatorname{SO}(\mathbb{O})$.  The orbit of $1 \in \mathbb{O}$ under $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ is the sphere of unit octonions, which we can identify with $S^7$.  The stabiliser of $1$ in $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ is precisely a $G_2$ subgroup.  This then gives the principal bundle
$$G_2 \to \operatorname{Spin}(7) \stackrel{\pi}{\to} S^7$$
with $\pi(g) = g \cdot 1$.

**Added**

Here is how to construct a local section of $S^7 \to
\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ near $1 \in S^7 \subset\mathbb{O}$ using
octonions.

Under the identification of $S^7$ with the unit-norm octonions, the
tangent space $T_1 S^7$ is identified with the imaginary octonions
$\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{O})$.  Let $\varphi$ denote the
$G_2$-invariant 3-form on $\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{O})$.  The image
of the map $\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{O}) \to
\Lambda^2\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{O})$ which sends $\xi$ to
$\iota_\xi \varphi$ is a $G_2$-invariant complement of $\mathfrak{g}_2
\subset \mathfrak{spin}(7)$, and we can exponentiate them to elements
of $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ near the identity.  Acting on $1 \in S^7$ 
we coordinatise a neighbourhood of $1$.

More explicitly, in case this is useful, the components
$\varphi_{ijk}$ of $\varphi$ relative to the basis $e_i$ above are
given by octonion multiplication as follows:
$$
e_i e_j = -\delta_{ij} 1 + \sum_{k=1}^7 \varphi_{ijk} e_k
$$
Then the point of $S^7$ with coordinates $\xi = \sum_{i=1}^7 \xi_i e_i \in
\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{O})$, is given by
$$
\exp\left(\tfrac12 \sum_{i,j,k=1}^7\xi_i \varphi_{ijk} L_j\circ L_k\right)
\cdot 1
$$
where the $L_j$ endomorphisms were defined above.

Comment: That's a nice description in terms principal bundles as to why there should be a local decomposition. However, without an explicit diffeomorphism $\pi^{-1}U\simeq U\times G_2$, it doesn't tell me how to decompose an element of $Spin(7)$.

Comment: Given that the explicit diffeomorphism $\pi^{-1}U\cong U\times G_2$ will fail to exist for $U$ too big, any formula describing it must be somewhat complicated (otherwise, it would make sense for $U=S^7$, which we know is impossible).

Comment: @Andre: We can consider elements of $Spin(7)$ as $7\times 7$ real matrices. What I'm looking for is a type of polar decomposition in terms of $G_2$. This doesn't have to be complicated.

Comment: @OliverJones why do you think you can write down elements of Spin(7) as real 7x7 matrices? Spin(7) is a nontrivial bundle over SO(7), its elements are not matrices.

Comment: José's clear and simple explanation also shows that Spin(7) can be written as a group of 8-by-8 matrices, not 7-by-7. As for a "polar decomposition", perhaps you (Oliver) should start by showing us what you mean for a simpler example such as the standard Hopf fibration $S^2 = S^3/S^1$.

Comment: David: OliverJones only cares about what happens locally. And locally, $Spin(7)$ and $SO(7)$ are the same,

Comment: @Deane: An example of what I'm talking about. Take hyperbolic space $H^3=SO(3,1)/SO(3)$. This is a Riemannian symmetric space of noncompact type. Elements of the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$ can be decomposed into a product of a rotation and a boost. This is by virtue of the fact that we have a Cartan decomposition at the Lie algebra level. The boosts $B({\bf u})$ can be parameterized by elements ${\bf u}\in H^3$ and it can be shown that $B({\bf u})B({\bf v})$=$B({\bf u}+{\bf v})O$ where $O$ is a rotation and ${\bf u}+{\bf v}$ is the relativistic velocity addition.

Comment: @OliverJones: The situation with hyperbolic space is slightly different.  First, $SO(3,1)$ is not connected, so what you have written is not strictly speaking hyperbolic space, but the full two-sheeted hyperboloid in Minkowski spacetime.  It may be better to write $H^3 = SL(2,\mathbb{C})/SU(2)$.  It is indeed the case that $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is (analytically, even) diffeomorphic to $SU(2) \times H^3$, but this is because $SU(2)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.  That's not the case in the example you are interested in.

Comment: (cont'd) Having said that, this example is different than the Hopf fibration is that whereas it is clear that $S^3$ and $S^2 \times S^1$ do not have the same de Rham cohomology, say, $Spin(7)$ and $G_2 \times S^7$ do.

Comment: What you can do for $G/K$, where $K$ is compact, is to fix a reductive decomposition $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak k + \mathfrak p$, namely, $[\mathfrak k,\mathfrak p]\subset\mathfrak p$. Then you can use the exponential map of $G$ restricted to $\mathfrak p$, fix a basis of $\mathfrak p$, and  use canonical coordinates of the first kind. This will give you local coordinates around the base point in $Spin_7/G_2$. In principle you can view $Spin_7$ as real matrices of order $8$, $G_2$ as a subgroup of matrices, and write a product decomposition in a nbhd of 1.

Comment: @ClaudioGorodski: I agree, but it seems to me that this works even if your split is not reductive.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: you are right, but I think we would probably like $K$ to be at least a closed subgroup.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill I think the situation is the same. By $SO(3,1)$ I mean the proper orthochronous Lorentz group  $SO^+(3,1)$, which is connected.

Comment: @ClaudioGorodski If you view $Spin_7$ as $8\times 8$ real matrices, what do you get for $\text{exp}\> {\frak p}$?

Comment: @OliverJones: You get exactly what I added to my answer.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: This answer is very interesting. I would like to add one correction. Matrices $L_i$ generate $C_6$ Clifford algebra, because $L_1...L_6=- L_7$. Product $R_1...R_6=R_7$.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle $G_2 \to Spin(7) \to S^7$ is nontrivial, indeed. The formula above
$$g_{S^7} =  \exp\left\{ \frac 12 \xi_j \phi_{jkl} \Gamma_k \Gamma_l \right \} \qquad \qquad  (1)$$
($\Gamma_j$ are the matrices $8 \times 8$ satisfying the Clifford algebra)
is a *local* section, but not a global section of this bundle.
It can be proven in quite explicit "physical" way. I do so in 2102.07415 [hep-th]. The digest of the proof is the following.

(1) is a section because

(*i*) Seven generators $T_j = \phi_{jkl} \Gamma_k \Gamma_l$ are orthogonal to 14 generators of $G_2$ and

(*ii*) (1) parameterize the whole $S^7$: the point $\xi_j = 0$ is its north pole with $g= \mathbb{1}$  and, if $\|\xi_j\| = \pi$, one obtains $g = - \mathbb{1}$, and this is the south pole.

However, (1) is not a global section by the following not quite trivial reason:

A subgroup $G_2 \subset Spin(7)$ are the matrices that do not transform a particular 8-component real spinor $\psi_0$. Consider the action of the matrices (1) on this spinor. One can show that $g \psi_0 = \cos(3\alpha) \psi_0 + \sin(3\alpha) \psi_1$, where $\alpha = \|\xi_j\|$ and $\psi_1$ is
some other spinor. If $\alpha = 0, \pm 2\pi/3$, $\psi_0$ is left intact. Thus, many elements of (1) belong to one and the same fiber of the bundle and hence (1) cannot be a section.